# Is it possible to write the current VS solution file from a VS package without having the File Modification Detected dialog

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsix, vspackage

From a VS package code, I wonder if there is an API to write the currently opened VS solution file without having the **File Modification Detected** dialog.

[image: VS File Modification Detected]

I need to write a custom `GlobalSection`:

```
GlobalSection(MyProduct) = preSolution
    MyData = "XYZ"
EndGlobalSection
```

I am aware of [IVsDocDataFileChangeControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsdocdatafilechangecontrol.aspx) and the associated [sample source code](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/8641B4F/98B3955E), but it seems the solution file object cannot be cast to [IVsPersistDocData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivspersistdocdata.aspx).
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.saveas.aspx ? (Also has Saved and IsDirty properties)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [`IVsSolutionPersistence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionpersistence.aspx) service, which you can obtain by passing `typeof(SVsSolutionPersistence)` to `GetService`. I'll try look into the details more later today.

> Facilitates writing package-specific properties and options into the solution file (.sln), and, conversely, the loading of properties and options from the file.

---

Ok, I finally found the time to dig into `IVsSolutionPersistence`. The amount of effort to use this interface is ridiculously high, so hopefully this answer will help some others people not wasting hours on this.

Basically you can save your options in the `.sln` *Solution* file, or in the `.suo` *Solution User Option* file. The `.sln` *Solution* file is suited to share options with everyone using the solution, the `.suo` *Solution User Option* file is suited to store/restore options only on the user local machine.

**STORAGE IN .SUO FILE**

To implement storage through the `.suo` *Solution User Option* file, you need that your Package class implements the interface [IVsPersistSolutionOpts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivspersistsolutionopts.aspx). The [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package(VS.100).aspx) class already implements this interface but you need to override all four methods in your package class. To get a sample implementation of this, you can refer to source code of this [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32906/Use-Visual-Studio-Extensibility-to-Make-a-Solution) article. Remarks:

- The stream provided by VS needs to be wrapped by a StreamEater class defined in this project? Apparently this [ComStreamWrapper class](https://github.com/pvginkel/VisualGit/blob/master/VisualGit.Services/VS/ComStreamWrapper.cs) does the same.
- When saving in `.suo` file, the user doesn't get any prompt dialog to ask to save the changes.
- When debugging your package through the VS experimental, you'll see that the `.suo` file is not getting actually written, I think VS experimental doesn't want to touch it (just my guess, not sure).
- `.suo` file storage is a proprietary binary storage. You can still open such file through a text reader and hopefully see your key/value data somehow.

**STORAGE IN .SLN FILE**

To implement storage through the `.sln` *Solution* file, you need that your Package class implements the interface [IVsPersistSolutionProps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivspersistsolutionprops.aspx). This interface implements the [IVsPersistSolutionOpts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivspersistsolutionopts.aspx) interface but it is not implement by the class [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.package(VS.100).aspx). The best existing implementation of this I found is in the project [VisualGit](https://github.com/pvginkel/VisualGit/blob/master/VisualGit.Package/VisualGitPackage.SolutionProperties.cs) source code. Remarks:

- You'll need to tag your package class with one or several [ProvideSolutionPropertiesAttribute["YourDataKey"]](https://github.com/pvginkel/VisualGit/blob/91a569ea946b4165e85e6212d0d0d7818f685fe2/VisualGit.Package/Attributes/ProvideSolutionProperties.cs). If you don't do that your implementation of the method `ReadSolutionProps()` won't be called.
- You'll need to wrap read/write accesses to [Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IPropertyBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.ole.interop.ipropertybag(v=vs.100).aspx) through the class [PropertyBag](https://github.com/pvginkel/VisualGit/blob/91a569ea946b4165e85e6212d0d0d7818f685fe2/VisualGit.Scc/Native/ICOMPropertyBag.cs). You'll have the choice to save data with quote, or just rawData. The section added in the `.sln` file will look like:

  ```
    GlobalSection(MY_SECTION_NAME) = preSolution
       MY_DATA = "12:02:45"
    EndGlobalSection
  ```
- In your implementation of the method `ReadSolutionProps()` of the method, you'll have to pass a [VSQUERYSAVESLNPROPS](http://technet.microsoft.com/subscriptions/index/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.vsquerysaveslnprops(v=vs.80)) value that will indicate to VS the storage state.
- The `.sln` file will be actually written when the user will close the solution, or close VS with the solution opened. The user will be prompted if she wants to modify the `.sln` file. If the user do Save-All, she won't be prompted for .sln file modifications, neither at Save-All time, neither at Close Solution time.

Comment: Do you know how IVsSolutionPersistence behaves with the File Modification Detected dialog and the source control checkout? If no, I'll check this later and will post my findings here. Thanks